# Can you change the view item output amount depending on user role?

Tags: views, users

Is there a way to do this within one view/display or do I have to make two seperate displays, one showing field_images with unlimited item output and one display showing field_images but only showing max 2 images - depending on user role?!

Comment: do you wan all the images or only images uploaded by the user?

Comment: all the images. basically i want to limit the amount of visible images per node to two for anonymous users, and unlimited to other roles. i would create two displays with different role and item amount setup but i wondered whether there is an easy way from within views directly

Comment: I dont see an option to do that. I think either two views or go with two fields one for anonymous user and one for authenticated user.

Answer (score 0):

I'd clone the view, the public one I'll name (temporarily) Public and change the access permission so anonymous users can view it.  The original one I'll name (again temporarily) Private and change the access to the authenticated user role.

Now you have two view displays, Public & Private.  Public display setting can be 2 and Private can be set to unlimited.

Comment: i know i could do it that way, my question was if there's another possibility doing it not like this :) but thank you anyways

Comment: View displays is the best way to make small changes to a view,it maintains the other views settings, so if you  change the view to display a teaser view mode, the change should trickle down to the other displays.

Comment: again, I know that :) thank you, that was not my question.